# Makefile : カレントディレクトリ以外にオブジェクトファイルを生成したい

Tags: c++, makefile

`make`において、以下の構成でプロジェクトを作成したいのですが、objディレクトリにオブジェクトファイルを格納するような`Makefile`はどのように作れば良いでしょうか。

**環境構成**

```
./
  ├ bin/     # 実行ファイル用ディレクトリ
  ├ include/ # インクルードファイル用ディレクトリ
  │  └ Util.h
  ├ obj/     # オブジェクトファイル用ディレクトリ
  ├ src/     # ソースコード用ディレクトリ
  │  ├ main.cxx
  │  └ Util.cxx
  └ Makefile
```

一応以下のやり方で実行ファイルの生成は出来ましたが、カレントディレクトリにオブジェクトファイルができてしまい、所望の動作ではないです。
(中途半端な変数化はスルーしてください･･･)

```
TARGET=./bin/test
SOURCES=$(wildcard src/*.cxx)
OBJECTS=$(notdir $(SOURCES:.cxx=.o))
VPATH=src

.SUFFIXES: .cxx .o

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    rm -f $@
    g++ -Wall -I./include -o $@ $^

.cxx.o:
    g++ -Wall -I./include -c $<

.PHONY: all clean
all:
    echo $(SOURCES)
    echo $(OBJECTS)
clean:
    rm -f *.o bin/*
```

オブジェクトファイルをobjディレクトリに格納するため、以下のようにしましたが、`make`時にエラーになってしまいます(`-c $<`が常に`Util.cxx`を指してしまう)。

```
TARGET=./bin/test
SOURCES=$(wildcard src/*.cxx)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst src/%.cxx, obj/%.o, $(SOURCES))

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    rm -f $@
    g++ -Wall -I./include -o $@ $^

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    g++ -Wall -I./include -o $@ -c $<

.PHONY: all clean
all:
    echo $(SOURCES)
    echo $(OBJECTS)
clean:
    rm -f bin/* obj/*
```

**実行結果**

```
$ make
g++ -Wall -I./include -o obj/Util.o -c src/Util.cxx
g++ -Wall -I./include -o obj/main.o -c src/Util.cxx # ここがNG。src/main.cxxになって欲しい
```

**環境**
`GNU Make 3.81`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

書いておられる Makefile の

```
$(OBJECTS) : $(SOURCES)
```

は `$(SOURCES)` から1回のアクションで `$(OBJECTS)` を出力するという意味になります。gcc コマンドの出力は1つですので出来ませんよね。(Makefile の $@ は出力先リストから1つしか取り出されません)
そこで以下の様に `%` を用いた指定を使います。

```
TARGET=./bin/test
SOURCES=$(wildcard src/*.cxx)
OBJECTS=$(addprefix obj/,$(notdir $(SOURCES:.cxx=.o)))

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    rm -f $@
    g++ -Wall -I./include -o $@ $^

obj/%.o : src/%.cxx
    g++ -Wall -I./include -o $@ -c $<

.PHONY: all clean
all:
    echo $(SOURCES)
    echo $(OBJECTS)
clean:
    rm -f bin/* obj/*
```

必要に応じて `.SUFFIXES: .o .cxx` を追加して下さい。

Comment: `$(OBJECTS) : $(SOURCES)`の意味をよく知りませんでした･･･ 
ちなみにこの構成で.SUFFIXESを使用して書くことができるのですか？サフィックスの使い方も勉強不足で基本の書き方ではダメでした。。

Comment: 今回の場合ですと、`%.o` という表記を期待しているので SUFFIXES は使え無さそうですね。